# How to set project owner in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, youtube, google-workspace

I have created a YouTube API key, but when I try to use it I get an error message that the key is not enabled. When I try to enable the key in the Google Cloud Console, I get the error message:

> IAM: you have insufficient permissions to enable or disable services
>   and APIs for this project. Contact a project owner to request
>   permissions.

I can't seem to find a way to set the project owner. I created this project myself, so I should be the project owner. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the account is managed via G-Suite.

Update: per the [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6304876), I logged on to G-Suite as an administrator and went to Apps > Additional Google services, but "Web & App Activity" is not listed as an option.

Comment: G Suite has some extra controls - Administrators can turn on/off services for users: https://support.google.com/a/answer/182442

Comment: Look up what roles are assigned to your account. Read the documentation on what roles you need. Update your question with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gsuite admin can activate the API or remove a restriction on it.

Answer (score 0):

To add an owner for a project, first select the project in the dropdown at the top of the screen. Then go to "IAM and Admin" in the navigation bar, then go to the IAM page. Click on "Add" at the top, and then you can add Project->Owner.

It can be confusing because even if somebody is an organization administrator, they aren't necessarily the owner of a project yet.